# Make global plan that includes obstacles from local costmap

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, costmap, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a navigation setup for a mobile robot. Local and global costmaps are running and navigation is working, however I would like to have the global planner replan when it sees obstacles in the local costmap. There are situations where it should come up with a new global plan because a pathway is blocked, but now the robot just stops. How can I make the global planner take local costmap obstacles into account if a pathway is blocked in order to generate a new global path?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363619/make-global-plan-that-includes-obstacles-from-local-costmap/) by [tropic](https://answers.ros.org/users/3186/tropic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 84 on 2020-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The culprit in my case was the plugins defined in the local and global costmap yaml-files. After removing those plugins and just using the normal settings everything works as expected.

The robot now makes a new global plan when its initial pathway is blocked, see the video below:
https://youtu.be/o6uR-MZ-jMY

---

Originally posted by [tropic](https://answers.ros.org/users/3186/tropic/) with karma: 84 on 2020-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0